# Retrieve first N records of a JSON array with a Postgresql query

Tags: json, postgresql

PostgreSQL has some native [JSON operations](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html) since verison 9.3. Suppose you have a table, `my_table`, with a `json` column, `my_json_col`, structured as follows:

```
[
  { "id": 1, "some_field": "blabla" },
  { "id": 2, "some_field": "foo" }
  ...
]
```

To retrieve the n-th element of `my_json_col`, you would execute something like: `SELECT my_json_col->n FROM my_table WHERE ...`. So if `n = 1`, the query would return the `"id": 2` record in my example.

I want to retrieve the first n elements, e.g. if `n = 2` the query should return the first two records in my example. Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you need to [convert the JSON array to a regular Postgres array](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54283/how-to-turn-json-array-into-postgres-array), then take a slice of it:

```
select (array_agg(e))[2:3]
from (select json_array_elements('[{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3},{"id":4}]'::json)) x(e);
```

If you need the result to be JSON, you can use `array_to_json`:

```
select array_to_json((array_agg(e))[2:3])
from (select json_array_elements('[{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3},{"id":4}]'::json)) x(e);
```

Comment: This works. The main reason I need this is because of performance - I may be dealing with some huge JSONs. Any ideas about `array_agg` and `json_array_elements` performance? Because if the entire JSON column is loaded in memory, then I'll need to think of something else.

Comment: I'm also interested in the performance implications of this. Has anybody tried this at scale?

Comment: Personally I'm not optimistic on perf if you have very long arrays. I doubt Postgres can avoid loading the whole thing as Step 1. If you need to select only some elements then I'd go for a more traditional table-based structure. But if you are really motivated to keep it all as JSON, I would just add a bunch of test data and run some benchmarks!

Answer (score 11):

In PostgreSQL 12, you can do:

```
SELECT jsonb_path_query_array('["a","b","c","d","e","f"]', '$[0 to 3]');
 jsonb_path_query_array
------------------------
 ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who will stumble here trying the same thing. Here is what I faced

I had a similar problem, I needed the N result from jsonb field which was containing an array. The result I needed was all the fields of the table and N number of data from the data field where the condition satisfies.

After going through this again and again I found out that the accepted answer aggregates the rows. So if you have a table

| id | type | data | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | employee | {{"age": 29, "name": "EMP 1"}, {"age": 30, "name": "EMP 2"},...} | Active |
| 2 | manager | {{"age": 28, "name": "MNG 1"}, {"age": 30, "name": "MNG 2"},...} | Active |

and you run the query

```
select (array_agg(e))[2:3]
from (select json_array_elements(data::json) from <table>) x(e);
```

then the output will be

| data |
| --- |
| {{"age": 30, "name": "EMP 2"}, {"age": 28, "name": "MNG 1"}} |

which was not needed in my case, What I needed was n data for each individual row where the condition satisfies e.g.

| data |
| --- |
| {{"age": 29, "name": "EMP 1"},{"age": 30, "name": "EMP 2"}} |
| {{"age": 28, "name": "MNG 1"},{"age": 30, "name": "MNG 2"}} |

so after searching a little and going through the [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54283/how-to-turn-json-array-into-postgres-array) provided by @Paul A Jungwirth
in the accepted answer. I found out that this can also be achieved by

`select (ARRAY(select json_array_elements_text(data::json)))[0:2]`

and the result will give you the n number of data from the jsonb field where the condition satisfies, you can also access other fields with it as well. Like let's say you want id and n number of data out of this table then you can do that just by adding id in the select query. (I was unable to get "id" in the query in the accepted answer)

`select id, (ARRAY(select json_array_elements(data::json)))[0:2] from table where condition`

will give output

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {{"age": 29, "name": "EMP 1"},{"age": 30, "name": "EMP 2"}} |
| 2 | {{"age": 28, "name": "MNG 1"},{"age": 30, "name": "MNG 2"}} |

Hope this will be helpful to someone.